# Is it possible to export a specific mail folder from Mail?

Tags: email

Is it possible to export a specific mail folder from Mail.app?

For example, I have a folder of mail messages containing invoices that I need to export and hand over to a new accountant.

In my search so far, I've only found a way to export my entire inbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Mail click the button **Show** which is in the top left of the application window:

   [image]
2. After step one you can see all your inboxes and folders. You can export any *inbox* or *folder* via the right-click menu dialog.

   [image]

Comment: The result of this export will be an mbox file. If you want to provide your accountant with PDF copies of attachments, or plaintext versions of the "invoice" messages, you'll have to use other methods.

Comment: @jaberg Yeah, the only other option that comes to mind is: 1) Select all emails in the folder 2) File > Save As 3) `.rtf`/`.txt`/`raw text file`

Comment: Your answer is dead on for the question as asked, I'm just not certain how useful an mbox file is going to be to the average accountant.

Comment: This answer works for my needs. The export is just going to be imported into another user's  Mail.app so the mbox format is great. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

If you want separate PDFs of your emails, just select the emails in question and hit print, choose PDF on the bottom of the window. (The naming of the PDFs is not necessarily the same as the email subject line, but it works.)

Comment: This doesn't work in Mountain Lion